# How can I modify template variables declared with :set?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following code (vue v3.2.33)

```html
<template v-for="route of routes" :key="route.name">
  <li :set="open = false">
    <div class="collapse"
      @click="open = !open"
      :class="[open ? 'collapse-is-open' :  '']">
    </div>   
  </li>
</template>
```

Basically each `li` has a collapse and opens with the class `collapse-is-open`.
I tried to use a variable with the `:set` attribute and modify that variable but it doesn't seem to work.

If that can't be working, what would be the other way of doing this ? An object based on the value I set in `:key` that keeps track of all the states?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles, and make them question sentences. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:set` is syntax for the `v-bind` directive. It binds a property/attribute on the element, but there is no such `set` property for `<li>`. I think you're trying to create an ad-hoc variable named `open` for each `<li>`, but that feature doesn't exist in Vue (perhaps you're thinking of `petite-vue`'s `v-scope`).

One solution is to create a separate data structure that contains the open-state of each `<li>`, and use that to update the `class` binding:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      routes: [⋯],
      open: {} // stores open-state of each route item
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template v-for="route of routes" :key="route.name">
  <li>
    <div class="collapse"
      @click="open[route.name] = !open[route.name]"
      :class="[open[route.name] ? 'collapse-is-open' :  '']">
    </div>   
  </li>
</template>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-toggle-class-on-click?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FRouteList.vue)

Alternatively, you could add that property to each array item in `routes`:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      routes: [
        {
          name: 'Route 1',
          open: false,
        },
        {
          name: 'Route 2',
          open: false,
        },
        {
          name: 'Route 3',
          open: false,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
```

```html
<template v-for="route of routes" :key="route.name">
  <li>
    <div class="collapse"
      @click="route.open = !route.open"
      :class="[route.open ? 'collapse-is-open' :  '']">
    </div>   
  </li>
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-toggle-class-on-click-7f6grc?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FRouteList.vue)